# When a user group is created, are there any group names that should be avoided?

Tags: users, group

There are many group names in `/etc/group` on a freshly installed Linux distribution. When creating a new group, are there any group names that should be avoided, outside of ones that already exist in `/etc/group`? Perhaps there are standards that I am unaware of. This question came to me the other day when making a a `share` group which seemed like a simple name and worked well. I would like to avoid name collisions with common services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't name a group the same thing as another group in `/etc/group`, you'll be fine.

Found a similar kind of question resulting from the original poster trying to install a web server. Just fyi, and if you wanted to dive into this more. Honestly, I've thought this is why you have GID's, so despite if a group name is the same, the GID will differentiate, but there you go. Always learning something new. :)

[Is it valid for two groups to have the same name (but different gid)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613564/is-it-valid-for-two-groups-to-have-the-same-name-but-different-gid)